# NextJS Image Repeating Incorrectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I am loading a series of images from Google Cloud Storage using the NextJS image component. Each image is identified in storage by a unique name, and when I load the URL using an  it always functions correctly. However, when I use a NextJS image component, some of the images repeat - looking at the addresses of the images, they indeed have the distinct and correct URLs, but the images shown are incorrect and repeats of ones with other names. My hunch is this is caused by cache, but I am unable to fix it.

I understand similar questions may have been asked before, but I have implemented those solutions to no avail. Specifically, I have tried:

1. Loading = "eager"
2. Setting Priority
3. Ensuring every src URL is unique

Has anyone encountered an issue like this, or have advice on what the driver could be? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.next` folder and running your dev server again?